Cannot open find dialog from menu
It seems the find dialog is broken in my Wolfram 14.1 (MacOS 14.5).
Evaluating the following code should bring up the find dialog:
FrontEndTokenExecute["FindDialog"]

but it does not.  In addition, clicking the menu item directly with my mouse doesn't bring up the dialog either.  All other dialogs seem to be working fine, whether I bring them up manually or programmatically.
Can anyone verify whether or not this is a bug?
Edit:  As Domen states below, the correct way to call the menu item programmatically is
FrontEnd`DialogOpen["Find.nb", True]

This solves my issue programmatically.  However, clicking the menu item with the mouse still doesn't work.

I can open find dialog with Ctrl+F or via menu or with FrontEnd`DialogOpen["Find.nb", True] with no problems in v14.1 on Windows. FrontEndTokenExecute["FindDialog"] doesn't work, but not even in v13.3. I don't us MacOS, but on Windows, sometimes a window can be moved outside of the screen (especially if you use external screens). Have you tried looking whether the window is actually opened? Have you tried resetting Wolfram?

@Domen Your programmatic solution works.  Thank you!  The menu still doesn't work.  I did check all windows, desktops, external screens, etc.  I will try resetting Wolfram as you instructed.  Thanks for sharing the page.  I didn't know about this.

The whole code for bringing up the dialog from the menu is actually KernelExecute[If[CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"], FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "FindExpression"], FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionSetFindEx"]; FrontEnd`DialogOpen["Find.nb", True]]] Can you try evaluating CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"]? It should come out as False. (I have no idea what is it's meaning, though.)

@Domen  Yes, it does come up as false and your second programmatic solution works too.  However, clicking on the menu item does not.  I recalled I installed a menu package item here that modified the keyevents translations a couple years ago, but I deleted last year and reset it when I installed 14.1.  I think I should be able to figure out the issue with the information you provided.  I keep you posted.  If it's a bug I will report that here too.  Thank you!

@Domen  It appears my menus somehow got corrupted. I found some code to reset them and posted in the solution below.  Do you recommend I delete this question entirely or leave it for others?

Resetting my Menus using the following code fixed the issue.
FrontEndExecute@{FrontEnd`FlushTextResourceCaches[],ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic,Automatic}]}

